# How to extract data from a specific column in the first CSV file to another column in another CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different CSV files which i have imported using `pd.read_csv`.

Both files have different header names. I would like to export this specific column under the header name of `["Model"]` in the first CSV file to the second CSV file under the header name of `["Product"]`

I have tried using the following code but produced value error:

```
writer=df1[df1['Model']==df2['Product']]
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you trying to join the two CSV files? Is there a common `key` between these?

Comment: Hi, i am trying to extract the column under header name "Model" in the first CSV file to the second CSV file under header name "Product". The second CSV file only consists of headers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by extract? What would you do if you were using excel? .. e.g copy the entire "Model" column and paste it into "Product"

Comment: I would like to copy the entire "Model" Column from df1.csv and paste it into "Product" column in a different csv file named "df2.csv". "Product" column in the "df2.csv" currently only consists of headers.

Comment: Have you tried joining the DataFrames on the index using `pandas.DataFrame.join` then exporting the result as a csv using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`?

Comment: What do you mean by  "only consists of headers"? Is this a problem or a statement? If there is no data to copy then do you just want to change the header name?

Comment: @charleen Do you want mean df2 is an empty dataframe with only column names and you want the column values of df1.Model under df2.Product? Then try df2.Product= df1.Model.copy() .

Comment: @nick It is a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try joining the DataFrames on the index using `pandas.DataFrame.join` then exporting the result as a csv using `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`.

```
df1.join(df2)
df1.to_csv('./df2.csv')
```